How can I restart a Compose Multiplatform app?
is there any way to relaunch app programmatically?
After changing language which is locale language but string resources doesn't update when app still alive. So I think that I need to relaunch app again. (referenced from this article KMP String Resources Handling With Locale

search for platform specific solutions, compose is just UI framework and it doesn't control activity by itself - not sure if the question is relevant for iOS

yeah that's right for android platform ok, I can do that but for iOS I don't know how to handle it!

so look for iOS solution. do you need it at all? iOS doesn't have activity to recreate, and the solution is going to be much dependent on how you the app is using strings from kmp. create a minimal reproducible example of how you're doing it and create a question with iOS tag
